# Amazon AWS - Cloudwatch. Creating a metric filter to create an alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, monitor

I'm trying to setup an alarm in cloudwatch. The monitor should search a specific string in logs such as:

> finished execution in the state Completed successfully

Below you can find the logs found in cloudwatch about the string:

```
@MESSAGE:  {"log":"[25/Mar/2021:16:04:21 +0000] category=BACKEND severity=NOTICE msgID=414 msg=Backup task recurringBackupTask-20210325160000000 finished execution in the state Completed successfully\n","stream":"stdout","docker":{"container_id":"389f974c00190dec6cb9bdf4617618b989078fc503ecbe8aff50aad2c0703cb9"},"kubernetes":{"container_name":"ds","namespace_name":"users","pod_name":"ds-cts-2","container_image":"912682637080.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/forgeops-v7/ds-cts@sha256:a7ef0afacbca756614228fbf4b518fc2c68d26ae67b6d013ef7ee13f053c97dd","container_image_id":"docker-pullable://912682637080.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/forgeops-v7/ds-cts@sha256:a7ef0afacbca756614228fbf4b518fc2c68d26ae67b6d013ef7ee13f053c97dd","pod_id":"8c776a54-6ab2-4089-a80f-9e4b171d694d","host":"ip-10-6-23-94.eu-central-1.compute.internal","labels":{"affinity":"directory","app":"ds-cts","controller-revision-hash":"ds-cts-5cd69c68bf","tier":"ds","app_kubernetes_io/managed-by":"skaffold","app_kubernetes_io/name":"forgerock","linkerd_io/control-plane-ns":"linkerd","linkerd_io/proxy-statefulset":"ds-cts","linkerd_io/workload-ns":"users","skaffold_dev/run-id":"forgeops-int-7","statefulset_kubernetes_io/pod-name":"ds-cts-2"},"master_url":"https://172.20.0.1:443/api","namespace_id":"438bb425-03db-4193-b007-7517f46f12d3","namespace_labels":{"app_kubernetes_io/name":"users","app_kubernetes_io/part-of":"users"}}}

LOG:       [25/Mar/2021:16:04:21 +0000] category=BACKEND severity=NOTICE msgID=414 msg=Backup task recurringBackupTask-20210325160000000 finished execution in the state Completed successfully
```

So I created this metric:

```
{($.kubernetes.container_name= "ds") && ($.log = "finished execution in the state Completed successfully")}
```

Once created the alarm and attached the metric, it seems not working because it can't find the string so it is always in alert state

What do you suggest? Is the metric wrong? I've already tried many combinations but nothing seems to work.

thanks in advance

best
MC

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{($.kubernetes.container_name= "ds") && ($.log = "*finished execution in the state Completed successfully*")}
```